# cannot download all the characters from a url in android

Tags: android

I have to download a certain json file and then store it as a text file in my application. For this i am using the following code:

```
public void readAndStoreFile() throws Exception {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(address);
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        int length = con.getContentLength();
        if (length > 0) {
            Log.i("lenght of bytes received", "" + length);
            InputStream fis = con.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String content = new String();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                content += line;
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = c.openFileOutput(filename,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    fos));
            bfw.write(content);
        } else
            throw new NegativeArraySizeException();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

But for some reason the whole json file is not being downloaded to the text file. Only a certain number of characters are downloaded and written after which the downloading and writing stops. Why is that happening?

The url that i am using is http://opisop.webuildapps.com/api/shops.json

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found out the answer , it was because of the 8k buffer capacity that only 8192 bytes were being read. I stripped out all the buffers and went to reading bytes using the inputstreamreader and it all worked out fine.